# Artefact in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Stripes appear when a texture with an alpha channel is applied

Is it possible to remove these stripes in Eevee?

This does not happen in Cycles.

[.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1duw0n-fyV_OuKFlaDnhBeZ8foQZkgd_O/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

---

Of course, the artifact is also visible on a white background.

And if green on a green background - the manifestation is more obvious in a static image.

[image]

Comment: Maybe use Closest instead of Linear texture interpolation in the Image Texture node, not sure why Linear doesn't work correctly though